# Can Eclipse rename/refatoring affect variables references at javadoc?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, javadoc

When over a variable/parameter/method name, if we press alt+shift+r, we can rename all usages of that identifier.

But, how can I create such identifier reference on the method's javadoc that will be recognized by eclipse and be automatically updated as the code is?

I have tried,
for local method variables {@code varName}, `<code>varName</code>`
for enums ${link EnumName.constantName}
...

nothing changes at javadoc when renaming/refactoring.

PS.: I am not talking about @param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you press Alt+Shift+R, click the small arrow on the right of the popup, then "Open Rename Dialog..." and select "Update textual occurences in comments and strings (forces preview)".
Eclipse will search for any occurrences and change them after showing you a preview. This works for classes, enums and also instance and class variables.

For local variables, this option is not available. I suppose the reason is, that there is generally no point in documenting local variables in Javadoc comments. You can use find/replace (Ctrl+F) as a workaround.

Comment: oh! my eclipse is Luna, which is yours? I cant see that option at the rename dialog

Comment: oh ok, I tried it on a parameter and it is considered as a local variable so that option will not show up :)